# How can I know which object I inherit

Tags: javascript, oop

In javascript how can I know which object I inehrit?
for example

```
function a() {
    this.c = 1;
}

function b() {
    this.d = 2;
}
b.prototype = new a();​
```

How can I check that b inherit from a?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
//capital letters indicate function should be used as a constructor
function A() {...}
function B() {...}
B.prototype = new A();
var a,
    b;
a = new A();
b = new B();

console.log(a instanceof A); //true
console.log(a instanceof B); //false
console.log(b instanceof A); //true
console.log(b instanceof B); //true
console.log(B.prototype instanceof A); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 b.prototype.constructor.name
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/psrcK/

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor property of `b.prototype` or any instance of `b`.

```
function a(){
  this.c=1;
}

function b(){
  this.d=2;
}

b.prototype=new a();

x = new b()

if(x.constructor == a){
    // x (instance of b) is inherited from a
}
```

Comment: Why when I do alert(x.constructor); its alert "function a(){
  this.c=1;
}"
but the x.constructor==a is work?

Comment: @user1801625 Because a is a function that has string representation `function a(){ this.c=1; }`

Answer (score 0):

of you probably want [instanceOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

```
if (b instanceOf a) {
    console.log("b is instance a")
}
```

This also has the advantage of walking the whole prototype chain so  it does not matter if it is a parent, grandparent, etc